# select multi inputs inside mutli div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im building a CRM application for products retail

in reciept form there could include multi products from the same category

here example for one category

```
<div id="frame_item">
<label>شنبر</label>
<input type="text" id="frame_code" name="frame_code" onfocus="autoSelectFrame(&quot;frame_code&quot;)">
<label>بيانات الشنبر</label>
<input type="text" id="frame_details" name="frame_details" disabled>
<label>سعر الشنبر</label>
<input type="text" id="frame_sell_price" name="frame_sell_price" value="5" class="frame_sell_price" disabled>
<label>الكمية</label>
<input type="text" id="frame_quantity" name="frame_quantity" class="frame_quantity" value="1" onchange="updateItemPrice(&quot;frame&quot;);">
<input type="text" id="frame_total_price" name="frame_total_price" class="frame_total_price" value="" disabled>
```

supposed onchange of quantity it changes the total price of the item

so this is the jquery code i made a custom function for it

```
function updateItemPrice(x)
{
    var finalPrice = 0;
    $(".frame_item").each(function(i){
        var quantity = $(".frame_quantity").val();
        var price = $(".frame_sell_price").val();
        finalPrice = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price);
        //$(".frame_total_price").val(finalPrice);
        alert(finalPrice);
    });
}
```

the problem it updates all with the same value

Comment: There are more than one frame_item? BTW, html says frame_item is id, but js code suppose frame_item is class. However, you code works somehow, as you said it "updates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `$(".frame_quantity")` and `$(".frame_sell_price")` search from the document root and they find all matching elements. Then `val()` retrieves the value of first matched element.

What you need is:

```
var finalPrice = 0;
$(".frame_item").each(function(i){
    var item = $(this);
    var quantity = item.find(".frame_quantity").val();
    var price = item.find(".frame_sell_price").val();
    finalPrice = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(price);
    item.find(".frame_total_price").val(finalPrice);
    alert(finalPrice);
});
```

This will trigger search for quantity and price inside the current item.

Also from jQuery selector I assume that `<div id="frame_item">` actually is `<div class="frame_item">`